# What kind of role has Functional Analysis played in Signal Processing?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ho.history-overview, applied-mathematics, signal-analysis

Does it serve mainly as a narration or is there any substantive consequence which might not be derived without tools of functional analysis?

Comment: This is an interdisciplinary site and here is a good interdisciplinary question, which should definitely stay open.

Comment: @PaulTaylor the problem with the question is not that it is interdisciplinary, but that it is very vague, broad, and possibly opinion based. (Furthermore, the site is not really interdisciplinary it is, as its on-topic says, for research level math questions.)

Comment: @quid, I did mean to propose a soft question, and I thought research level math question could be a history topic.

Comment: Historical questions can be on-topic yet not if they are vague, broad, and possibly opinion based.

Answer (score 4):

The theory of (unconditional and other) bases of Banach and Hilbert spaces has certainly
played a role in the formulation of Gabor frames and bandwidth restricted frames in signal processing. And Fourier expansion served was a model.